# Dart Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String', error Showing in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, dart-null-safety, dio

I'm trying to build a note app on local host. and when I try to call a Function for get all data's from the database this error has thrown . here is the error output console log

```
[ERROR:flutter/shell/common/shell.cc(93)] Dart Unhandled Exception: type
'_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String', stack trace: #0

NoteDB.getAllNotes (package:crud_operations/data/data.dart:105:51)

 <asynchronous suspension>
 #1      HomePage.build.<anonymous closure>
(package:crud_operations/homescreen.dart:22:7)
 <asynchronous suspension>
```

**as the error saying** `[ HomePaage.build package:crud_operations/homescreen.dart:22:7]` ,
here is the homepage 22nd line code
(the code that trying to call that function)

```
//homepage code .. the code of calling get all data funciton

WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_) async {
      await NoteDB.instance.getAllNotes();
    });
```

**and here is the getAllNotes() function**

```
@override
  Future<List<NoteModel>> getAllNotes() async {
    
    //patching all data from local server using the url from [Post Man]
    final _result = await dio.get(url.baseUrl+url.getAllNotes);
    if (_result.data != null) {
      //if the result data is not null the rest operation will be operate
      //recived data's data decoding to json map
      final _resultAsJsonMap = jsonDecode(_result.data);
      //and that map converting to dart class and storing to another variable
      final  getNoteResponse = GetAllNotes.fromJson(_resultAsJsonMap);
      noteListNotifier.value.clear();
      noteListNotifier.value.addAll(getNoteResponse.data.reversed);
      
      noteListNotifier.notifyListeners();
      //and returning the class
      return getNoteResponse.data;
    } else {
      noteListNotifier.value.clear();
      return [];
    }

  }
```

**important note** : I tried the printing all debugging method :)

and i think the error is here `final _resultAsJsonMap = jsonDecode(_result.data);`

and also here is the complete code git hub repository : https://github.com/Mishalhaneef/Note-app

if I miss any part that you want to find what actually problem is, please comment, I Will update, or check the git hub code link below

Comment: I think ```_result.data``` is already a ```JsonMap``` and you do not need to decode it.

Comment: worked really thanks, and there is another problem, the value not displayin gafter adding but after restarting, i dont know why